# Can a PHP script unserialize a Storable file created with Perl?

Tags: php, perl, serialization, storable

Can a PHP script unserialize a Storable file created with Perl?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, but you can dump PHP-readable data from Perl with [PHP::Serialization](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?PHP::Serialization).  You also might want to pick something more standard, like YAML or JSON.  Pretty much any language can understand those.

Comment: Well, you could do it if you rewrote Storable as a PHP library, couldn't you? :)

Comment: Good luck mapping Storable's concepts onto PHP (like blessed references).

Answer (score 5):

You could use JSON as a lingua-franca between the two languages, I suggest [JSON::XS](http://search.cpan.org/%7Emlehmann/JSON-XS-2.2311/XS.pm) on the Perl side (with subroutines implemented in C/C++) for performances, then you can read back (in PHP) the JSON with [this extension](https://www.php.net/json).

Answer (score 4):

PHP being Turing-complete and all, the answer isn't really "no" so much as "not natively or with any well-known public module".

Comment: Um... no.  Read the question.  YAML is a solution for transferring serialized data between PHP and Perl; it is not a solution for *reading serialized data from Perl's Storable module into PHP*.

Comment: Okay, you weren't being helpful with the early kick-out, then. BTW, thanks for all the downvotes with posts that each one contains about 3-times more helpful detail than your early kick-out.)

Comment: This is faintly ridiculous, since it's right there in front of you that I wrote my answer an hour after the other two.  But I guess you've already demonstrated reading comprehension issues.  I wrote what I wrote because the accepted answer's "no" isn't really true.

Comment: Early kick-out="Test. No? -> Done." Like a flowchart. Actually, my reading comprehension is fine--when I reread a source. By the time I read down the page, I had forgotten the actual context. You helped me realize that the question--as asked--hadn't been answered.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Well, glad to be of service, then.  I guess it all worked out in the end.

Answer (score 4):

As chaos points out, you asked for [*Storable*](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Storable) specifically, and so switching to YAML (or JSON) *may* be possible, but it may not. This might work to get it into [YAML](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?YAML::Syck) (or even [JSON](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?JSON::Syck)):

```
$output_format = 'YAML';
popen( "perl -MStorable -M${output_format}::Syck=Dump -e 'print Dump( retrieve( q{$storable_file_path} ))'", "r" );
```

Comment: If you're going to exec Perl for every request, why would you be using PHP to begin with?

Comment: Jon (rockway), who said anything about exec-ing it every request? 
You could substitute -MPHP::Serialization=serialize and print serialize( retrieve( ... )), you can fwrite that string to a file or but you'd still have to fread it, no matter what.